# How to efficiently bucket pandas data frames and then perform groupby operations on those buckets?

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to bucket volumes and build up a summary report over the aggregate data via those buckets. Currently I use **apply** to do this, but **apply** can be very slow for large data sets. Is there a generic form of the syntax given in create_lt_ten_buckets? I'm guessing this is more of a numpy thing, with which I am less familiar.

```
def create_buckets(df_internal, comparison_operator, column_to_bucket, min_value, max_value, ranges_pivots):
    low = [min_value] + ranges_pivots
    high = ranges_pivots + [max_value]
    ranges = list(zip(low, high))
    max_str_len = len(str(max(high + low)))
    def get_value(row):
        count = 0
        for l,h in ranges:
            if comparison_operator(l, row[column_to_bucket]) and comparison_operator(row[column_to_bucket], h):
                return "{}|{}_to_{}".format(str(count).zfill(max_str_len),l,h)
            count+=1
        return "OUTOFBAND"
    df_internal["{}_BUCKETED".format(column_to_bucket)] = df_internal.apply(get_value, axis=1)

def create_lt_ten_bucket(df_internal, column_to_bucket):
    df_internal["{}_is_lt_ten".format(column_to_bucket)] = df_internal[column_to_bucket] < 10

dftest = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5, 44, 250, 22], columns=["value_alpha"])
create_buckets(dftest, lambda v1,v2: v1 <= v2, "value_alpha", 0, 999, [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200])
display(dftest)


create_lt_ten_bucket(dftest, "value_alpha")
display(dftest)

dftest.groupby('value_alpha_BUCKETED').sum().sort_values('value_alpha_BUCKETED')
```

```
OUTPUT
value_alpha value_alpha_BUCKETED
0   1   000|0_to_1
1   2   001|1_to_2
2   3   002|2_to_5
3   4   002|2_to_5
4   5   002|2_to_5
5   44  005|25_to_50
6   250 008|200_to_999
7   22  004|10_to_25
```

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5, 44, 250, 22], columns=["value_alpha"])
create_buckets(dftest, lambda v1,v2: v1 <= v2, "value_alpha", 0, 999999999, [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200])
display(dftest)
```

```
create_lt_ten_bucket(dftest, "value_alpha")
display(dftest)
```

```
OUTPUT
value_alpha value_alpha_BUCKETED    value_alpha_is_lt_ten
0   1   000|0_to_1  True
1   2   001|1_to_2  True
2   3   002|2_to_5  True
3   4   002|2_to_5  True
4   5   002|2_to_5  True
5   44  005|25_to_50    False
6   250 008|200_to_999  False
7   22  004|10_to_25    False
```

In the end I'm trying to get a summary of the data similar to this:
`dftest.groupby('value_alpha_BUCKETED').sum().sort_values('value_alpha_BUCKETED')`

```
    value_alpha value_alpha_is_lt_ten
value_alpha_BUCKETED        
000|0_to_1  1   1.0
001|1_to_2  2   1.0
002|2_to_5  12  3.0
004|10_to_25    22  0.0
005|25_to_50    44  0.0
008|200_to_999  250 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but what you have is roughly `pd.cut` and `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
dftest['new_bucket'] = pd.cut(dftest['value_alpha'], [0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 999])
dftest['value_alpha_is_lt_ten'] = dftest['value_alpha'] < 10
print(dftest.groupby("new_bucket").sum())

            value_alpha  value_alpha_is_lt_ten
new_bucket                                    
(0, 1]                1                    1.0
(1, 2]                2                    1.0
(2, 5]               12                    3.0
(5, 10]               0                    0.0
(10, 25]             22                    0.0
(25, 50]             44                    0.0
(50, 100]             0                    0.0
(100, 200]            0                    0.0
(200, 999]          250                    0.0
```

If you don't want the empty buckets, you could `.query` on values where `value_alpha > 0`